# How to control build execution in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015

1. Developer A is member of group - 'Contributors' and 'Project Valid Users' for team project T1. He is required to perform all development activities like check-in, check-out, merge etc.
2. There are 3 builds configured for this team project T1. One each to build and copy artifacts to Dev, QA and Production servers.

Currently  'A' is not able to modify the build but he can execute (queue build) the builds.

We need to control this build executions. We want only few members (project owner) to execute the build (& deployment) of QA and Prod.

Please advise how to provide the authority to control the same.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the build in Visual Studio (or possibly the web interface) and select "Security"? You should be able to control which users/groups have access to which functions for each build definition.

Comment: yes, it worked. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by permissions. You can add all the project owner to the group - Project collection build Administrators. Setting the premissions to make sure **only this group can queue the related build**. More info about detail permissions for your reference: [MSDN Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#collection)

To setting the permission, you can do this in the web portal( click the security just as below) or using [tf permission command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command)

*Note:* My screenshot is for TFS 15, not for TFS2015, there maybe something difference.
[image]

Comment: Update screenshot, the related permission is *Queue builds*